# Renaming files in commandline?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, line, rename

When paste a script manualy in CMD and hit enter it renames the file in the same directory as expected. When i place it into a batch and run the batch as admin noting happens.
Original filename: Scores Clients MAX values (datevalue).xlsx
Target filename: Scores Clients MAX values.xlsx
So i need to cut off the date values. The filename contains spaces, filename without spaces not really an option.

@echo off

set filename=Scores Clients MAX values

I:

cd Share\ETL_files\

rename "%filename%*" "%filename%.xlsx"

Comment: Is `I:` a network drive? It simply might not be connected when you run the script "as administrator" (different user context).

Comment: After some trial and error i found the solution. The filepath should be in front of the source file, as: RENAME "I:\Share\ETL_files\%filename%"  "%filename%.xlsx"

Comment: if you found a solution, consider adding it as a answer. note : its totally okay to post an answer to your own question.